# Is this OCaml function composition operator definition/expression correct?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, function-composition

```
let (++) f g x = f (g x) in
    let f x = x + 1 in
    let g x = x * 2 in
    (f++g) 1;;
```

1. **Is the above expression correct?**
2. It seems to me that the above code should be just like defining `f++g x = 2 * x + 1`. Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation of function composition is correct, since :

> (g ∘ f)(x) = g(f(x)) for all x in X

according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)

I get :

```
- : int = 3
```

in ocamlktop